# infection by/from the virus

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> Working in an unsanitized environment subjects people to infection **from** viruses.

> Working in an unsanitized environment subjects people to infection **by** viruses.

Which preposition is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ansonman.
Well, in this case we should use the second one.

Why?
Well, we must use a preposition that indicates “agent or cause” and “by” is your best option.

You can read more information about it in this website:
https://www.spanishdict.com/compare/by/from

Comment: Thank you for your reply and the source.